# Tags within context data in helper

Tags: dust.js

I'm trying to solve for a scenario where data can contain tags that refers to other data. So if my dust file looked like this:

```
Document.title: {Document.title}
cfg.title: {cfg.title}
output: {#ctx key="{cfg.title}" /}
```

and my context looks like this:

```
{
  cfg: {
    title: '{Document.title}'
  }
  , Document: {
    title: 'Here is my title'
  }
  , ctx: function(chunk, context, bodies, params){
    return context.resolve(params.key);
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Document.title: This is the title
cfg.title: {Document.title}
output:
```

What does my "ctx" helper function need to look like to get it to output "Here is my title"? (note: I know it would be easier to just point to Document.title, but 'cfg' and 'Document' are being generated from different places and are merged at render time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you have to compile (or otherwise parse) the minitemplate that forms your config. Here is one possible approach, where I use `dust.compile` to build the config in advance:

```
{
  cfg: {
    title: dust.compile('{Document.title}')
  }, Document: {
    title: 'Here is my title'
  }, ctx: function(chunk, context, bodies, params){
    eval(params.key)(chunk, context);
  }
}
```

With the template:

```
{#ctx key=cfg.title /}
```

Note that you are passing `cfg.title` directly here instead of stringifying it first-- this is important so that you don't have to use `context.resolve` to do a double-lookup.

This approach does not generate a template-readable `cfg.title`, so if that is important to you, you can move the `dust.compile` step to inside the `ctx` function.

Comment: This will work. Thank you!

Note to anyone finding this answer, if you're working on Dust prior to 2.7, you'll need to add a second param to dust.compile.